# The word "Unlockable"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, prefixes, morphology

*Unlockable(unlock-able)* usually means something that can be unlocked.

Ex:

- That door is unlockable.

However, I noticed that you can say the opposite... *Unlockable(un-lockable)*. Something that can ***not*** be locked.

While I know that this sounds SO unnatural, but I do think that this word usage is still valid.

I do not plan on using that word, but, will native speaker can still get the meaning of it if the context is given?

Like, ***I can't lock this door, it's unlockable!***. I know that we normally use *It can't be locked*(the door can't be locked), but I can't seem to get it out of my head.

<s>Also, is there any other words that work like this?</s>→I've found a [Wikitionary page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_contranyms), I couldn't find "unlockable" though :P

Comment: "This door can't be locked." is sufficient. It would apply to you or anyone else. Unfortunately, "unlockable" could also be interpreted as (able to unlock) which is opposite of what you want. You should just avoid the word.

Comment: @user3169 Yeah, and that's why I wrote *I do not plan on using that word...* I was just curious about if it can be used that(un-lockable) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use *unlockable* in that sense because it has a common, overriding meaning: if a thing is *unlockable*, it can be unlocked.
That is it can be changed from a locked state to an unlocked state.
For your meaning, you can use *not lockable*.

Comment: So, is *un-lockable* still valid? it's not like I'm going to use in that way, but I'm so curious about it...

Comment: Yes, it's valid in both senses, though it would be confusing. But in current spelling, it has no hyphen.

Comment: Oh yes, I just added hyphen for clarification. Thanks for your answer&reply!

Comment: Good find, the Wikipedia page for contranyms.